# c++ reference: What is the difference in the two statements?

Tags: c++, reference

I am confused by the meaning of the codes.

```
int x= 25;
x = int &y; vs int &y=x;
```

I tried testing it out and noticed one of the case is an error. But i do not get the difference between the two codes.

Comment: Seems like you need a [good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: What about `int x = 25;` and `25 = int x;` do you understand why they are different? It the same with your example, if you don't get the syntax correct you code will not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first case is not a legal code in C++.
in the second one, you are telling the compiler to give `x` another name which is `y`.
That's called reference

Comment: I see, then what about a standalone int &y? Does this mean a reference to y or a reference from y? I see this syntax used in defining a constructor under the section for copy constructor ie `Rectangle(Rectangle &r)`

Comment: @Shane In that case `r` will be bound to the object being copied. It's no different to any other function parameter, the value depends on how it is called.

Comment: @john When you say the value depends on how it is called, what do you mean?

Comment: @Shane Are you familar with the concept of a function parameter? The value of a function parameter depends on how the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the first case will give you an error, because y is not defined. On the other hand, you are creating another variable and so you can. It's like saying 25 = something, of course it cannot be like so, but something = 25 is okay.